# When trying to execute a delete Mutation in React Apollo I get an Unhandled Rejection (Error): Response not successful: Received status code 400

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo

I'm still new to GraphQL and currently working on a project management application. Users can create projects with have an array of specific tasks. Now I'm trying to use a deleteTask mutation to delete a specific task. The individual tasks are rendered in a TaskList component where I map through the array and pass down props to the TaskListItem component.

Here's my code in the client, first the mutation:

```
export const DELETE_TASK_MUTATION = gql`
mutation deleteTask($projectId: ID!, $taskId: ID!) {
    deleteTask(projectId: $projectId, taskId: $taskId) {
        id 
        userId
        createdAt 
        artist 
        venue
        date
        time
        projectType
        result
        note1
        note2
        gage
        tasks {
            id
            name
            projectId
            done 
            duedate
        }
    }
}`
```

The TaskListItem component:

```
export default TaskListItem(props) {
  const projectId = props.projectId
  const taskId = props.id

  const [deleteTask, { error }] = useMutation(DELETE_TASK_MUTATION, {
      variables: {
          projectId,
          taskId
      }
  })

  if (error) console.log(error)

  return(
      <div className="task">
          <div className="taskName">{props.name}</div>
          <div className="taskIcons">
              <IconButton aria-label="Löschen" onClick={deleteTask}>
                  <CloseIcon />
              </IconButton>
          </div>
      </div>
  )
```

}

And this is the typeDef and resolver from the backend. The server code seems to work though cause I can execute the mutation in the playground.

```
typeDefs.js:

deleteTask(projectId: ID!, taskId: ID!): Project!

resolvers.js:

const { AuthenticationError, UserInputError } = require('apollo-server');
const Project = require('../../models/Project');
const checkAuth = require('../../util/check-auth');

module.exports = {
Mutation: {
    async deleteTask(_, { projectId, taskId }, context) {
        const user = checkAuth(context);

        const project = await Project.findById(projectId);

        if (project) {
            const taskIndex = project.tasks.findIndex((t) => t.id === taskId);

            if (project.userId === user.id) {
                project.tasks.splice(taskIndex, 1); 
                await project.save();
                return project;
            } else {
                throw new AuthenticationError('Action not permitted')
            }
        } else { 
            throw new UserInputError('Project not found');
        }
    }
  }
```

};

I already tried to change the expected types for projectId and taskId to Strings both in the typeDefs and the mutation but it throws the same error every time. I'm kind of stuck, hope anyone can give me some pointers. Thanks a lot!

Here's the full error page from the browser:

```
Unhandled Rejection (Error): Response not successful: Received status code 400

ApolloError
src/errors/index.ts:56

  53 | // Constructs an instance of ApolloError given a GraphQLError
  54 | // or a network error. Note that one of these has to be a valid
  55 | // value or the constructed error will be meaningless.
> 56 | constructor({
  57 | ^  graphQLErrors,
  58 |   clientErrors,
  59 |   networkError,

error
src/core/QueryManager.ts:307

  304 | 
  305 |   reject(
  306 |     err instanceof ApolloError ? err : new ApolloError({
> 307 |       networkError: err,
  308 |  ^  }),
  309 |   );
  310 | },

makeCallback/<
src/utilities/observables/asyncMap.ts:48

  45 |       });
  46 |     };
  47 |   } else {
> 48 |     return arg => delegate && delegate.call(observer, arg);
  49 | ^  }
  50 | }
  51 | 

iterateObserversSafely/<
src/utilities/observables/iteration.ts:13

  10 |   // to just the observers with the given method.
  11 |   const observersWithMethod: Observer<E>[] = [];
  12 |   observers.forEach(obs => obs[method] && observersWithMethod.push(obs));
> 13 |   observersWithMethod.forEach(obs => (obs as any)[method](argument));
  14 | }
  15 | 

iterateObserversSafely
src/utilities/observables/iteration.ts:13

  10 |   // to just the observers with the given method.
  11 |   const observersWithMethod: Observer<E>[] = [];
  12 |   observers.forEach(obs => obs[method] && observersWithMethod.push(obs));
> 13 |   observersWithMethod.forEach(obs => (obs as any)[method](argument));
  14 | }
  15 | 

error
src/utilities/observables/Concast.ts:185

  182 |     this.sub = null;
  183 |     this.latest = ["error", error];
  184 |     this.reject(error);
> 185 |     iterateObserversSafely(this.observers, "error", error);
  186 | ^  }
  187 | },
  188 | 

createHttpLink/</</<
src/link/http/createHttpLink.ts:201

  198 |       // and use correct http status codes
  199 |       observer.next(err.result);
  200 |     }
> 201 |     observer.error(err);
  202 | ^  });
  203 | 
  204 | return () => {
```

Here's the errors I get in the browser console:

```
Error: Response not successful: Received status code 400

ApolloError index.ts:56
error QueryManager.ts:307
notifySubscription module.js:137
onNotify module.js:176
error module.js:229
makeCallback asyncMap.ts:48
notifySubscription module.js:137
onNotify module.js:176
error module.js:229
iterateObserversSafely iteration.ts:13
iterateObserversSafely iteration.ts:13
error Concast.ts:185
notifySubscription Observable.js:140
onNotify Observable.js:179
error Observable.js:240
notifySubscription module.js:137
onNotify module.js:176
error module.js:229
createHttpLink createHttpLink.ts:201
TaskListItem.js:35

Uncaught (in promise) Error: Response not successful: Received status code 400

ApolloError index.ts:56
error QueryManager.ts:307
notifySubscription module.js:137
onNotify module.js:176
error module.js:229
makeCallback asyncMap.ts:48
notifySubscription module.js:137
onNotify module.js:176
error module.js:229
iterateObserversSafely iteration.ts:13
iterateObserversSafely iteration.ts:13
error Concast.ts:185
notifySubscription Observable.js:140
onNotify Observable.js:179
error Observable.js:240
notifySubscription module.js:137
onNotify module.js:176
error module.js:229
createHttpLink createHttpLink.ts:201
```

Since this seems to be a network error I want to add that I'm running both the server and the client on my local machine and I have several queries and other mutations in this app that work as expected and without errors.

Comment: There must be more error logs like what gone wrong. Can you provide some of these?

Comment: Added the entire error messages I get.

Comment: Thsi looks like a connection poblem with you backend, else the response will be 200 and errors will occure inside your response object

Comment: Thank you for your answers. That's what I thought. But I already have three queries and three other mutations set up in this app and all of them are working exactly as expected, so I really don't get it at this point.